# How to get the SFMC abandoned cart link to go to the abandoned cart page and not to the products page

Tags: email

I am using the abandon cart behavioral trigger content area in an abandoned cart email and it works fine if I want the product link to go to the product page but I don't. I want the links to go to the cart that was abandoned and can't figure out how to do that. There is zero documentation on this. I am unable to make changes to the links in MC because they are coming from the encoded DATA field in abandoned_cart.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of this site is a description about the possibilities on how to re-create carts: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=icx_b2c_abandonedcart_configurations.htm&type=5